# How to write a general expression for $n-$th element?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the general expression for $n-$th element?
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
k & 24 & 69 & 214 & 747 & 2820  & ...\\
\end{array}$$

I have tried several methods like recurrence relation formula of finite differences.

Comment: They are already a mathematical expression.

Comment: @5xum You must feel very clever.

Comment: @uniquesolution A lazy, vague question deserves a lazy, vague answer.

Comment: @5xnum Not everyone are well versed in mathematical formalism as you are. People are trying to communicate their questions. If you understand the question - which I assume you do -- then there is no need being condescendant.

Comment: @uniquesolution A person who knows about Nash equilibria and linear programming should also know why this question is bad.

Comment: The table of finite differences tells us little, except that the ratio of the third order differences (there are two of them) is exactly $4$.

Comment: Where did these numbers come from and why do you expect some kind of relation between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

$$24,69,214,747,2820,...$$

Is already a "mathematical" expression. But that is probably not what you mean. You probably want a general expression for the $n$-th element in your sequence, and if you want that, the answer....

**does not exist**.

---

You didn't give enough information about the sequence for us to answer your question. For example, the sequence could be

$$24,69,214,747,2820,0,0,0,0,0,0\dots$$

in which case the mathematical expression for the sequence would be

$$a_n=\begin{cases}24&n=1\\ 69&n=2\\214&n=3\\ 747 & n=4 \\ 2820& n=5\\ 0&n\geq 6\end{cases}$$

Given your information, there is nothing that prevents the sequence being like that. Or, being $$24,69,214,747,2820,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\dots$$
or
$$24,69,214,747,2820,93485,34598345,23489234,23497234,4589567$$

or whatever other sequence you want to think of.

---

If you want a **polynomial** that fits your data, then the lowest degree polynomial is

$$f(x)=36x^4−312x^3+1022x^2−1377x+655$$

(for this polynomial, you have $f(1)=24,f(2)=69,f(3)=214, f(4)=747, f(5)=2820$).

However, there are **infinitely many** other polynomials that fit your data, if you allow the polynomials to have degree $5$.

Comment: For such questions, a minimum description length should be considered.

Comment: This is a serious candidate for the most useless answer ever.

Comment: @uniquesolution Much constructive, such insight.

Comment: @5xum thank you for the description. How did you obtain the polynomial of degree 4?

Comment: @MOP http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html

Comment: @5xum Thank you very much! Anyway, that polynomial does not fit my data! $f(6)$ does not give the correct answer

Comment: @MOP Well that just proves my point. My point was not that the polynomial is the correct solution, but that it is one out of a set of **infinitely many** solutions. Without further info on the data, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: @5xum I think Lagrange Interpolation is not a good method to find a general expression for $n-$th element. I tried it. It doesn't give the correct answer. Are there any other methods?

Comment: @MOP this would be much easier if you gave some more info about where the data comes from...

Comment: @5xum I have added more details to my question. Does it help to write the general case?

Comment: @MOP "one more data point" and "some more info about where the data comes from" is not the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

The logarithm of the numbers grows in a roughly linear fashion

[image]